# Spooled SQL output to CSV

Tags: bash, oracle, shell, csv, command-line

I have input data of 4GB from spooled sql command as below:

### Head

```
SQL> select * from hist_tran_monthly;
   250,            10,         0,R,    199801,      4155,      199801
  2222,31-JAN-98
   250,            10,         0,R,    199802,      4155,      199802
 11111,28-FEB-98
   250,            10,         0,C,    199803,      4155,      199803
 11111,31-MAR-98
   250,            10,         0,R,    199807,      4155,      199807
 28934,29-JUN-98
   250,            10,         0,R,    199808,      4155,      199808
```

### Tail

```
    701679,           485,         1,C,    201001,    222.76,      201311
  14112013,14-NOV-13
    701679,           485,         1,C,    201002,    222.76,      201311
  14112013,14-NOV-13
    701679,           485,         1,C,    201003,    222.76,      201311
  14112013,14-NOV-13
    701679,           485,         1,C,    201004,    229.69,      201311
  14112013,14-NOV-13
42912030 rows selected.
SQL> spool off
```

I need to get such output.csv

### Output

```
       250,            10,         0,R,    199801,      4155,      199801,      2222,31-JAN-98
       250,            10,         0,R,    199802,      4155,      199802,     11111,28-FEB-98
       250,            10,         0,C,    199803,      4155,      199803,     11111,31-MAR-98
       250,            10,         0,R,    199807,      4155,      199807,     28934,29-JUN-98
...
    701679,           485,         1,C,    201001,    222.76,      201311,  14112013,14-NOV-13
    701679,           485,         1,C,    201002,    222.76,      201311,  14112013,14-NOV-13
    701679,           485,         1,C,    201003,    222.76,      201311,  14112013,14-NOV-13
    701679,           485,         1,C,    201004,    229.69,      201311,  14112013,14-NOV-13
```

How do I remove top one and last two lines and remove alternate line breaks and insert comma instead to make it a `csv` file.

Comment: your sample input has at least 73 visible characters on the longest line; from this I'm going to assume your SQL client is wrapping the SQL results at ~80 characters; before writing a script to eliminate the premature line wraps you may want to see if your SQL client has a (command line) option to extend the width of the output (eg, `isql` has the `-w <number_of_columns>` that allows for 'wide' output (eg, `-w 1000`)

Comment: The output was taken from Oracle 8i DB, I don't think that `isql` command can be used with it

Comment: I'm not saying to use `isql`, I'm saying that whatever tool you're using (`sqlplus`? `sqldeveloper`?) may have an option similiar to `isql`'s `-w` option; for Oracle does `set line` work to increase the width?

Comment: Yes, that helped!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this is your `data.txt`:

```sql
SQL> select * from hist_tran_monthly;
   250,            10,         0,R,    199801,      4155,      199801
  2222,31-JAN-98
   250,            10,         0,R,    199802,      4155,      199802
 11111,28-FEB-98
   250,            10,         0,C,    199803,      4155,      199803
 11111,31-MAR-98
   250,            10,         0,R,    199807,      4155,      199807
 28934,29-JUN-98
   250,            10,         0,R,    199808,      4155,      199808
    701679,           485,         1,C,    201001,    222.76,      201311
  14112013,14-NOV-13
    701679,           485,         1,C,    201002,    222.76,      201311
  14112013,14-NOV-13
    701679,           485,         1,C,    201003,    222.76,      201311
  14112013,14-NOV-13
    701679,           485,         1,C,    201004,    229.69,      201311
  14112013,14-NOV-13
42912030 rows selected.
SQL> spool off
```

You can use head/tail to remove 1 line from the top and 2 lines from the bottom:

```sh
# tail -n +2 : removes top line
# head -n -2 : remove 2 lines from the end
$ tail -n +2 data.txt | head -n -2
```

There are other ways that may work better, this is the way I'd use.

Edit: This is the output:

```sql
   250,            10,         0,R,    199801,      4155,      199801
  2222,31-JAN-98
   250,            10,         0,R,    199802,      4155,      199802
 11111,28-FEB-98
   250,            10,         0,C,    199803,      4155,      199803
 11111,31-MAR-98
   250,            10,         0,R,    199807,      4155,      199807
 28934,29-JUN-98
   250,            10,         0,R,    199808,      4155,      199808
    701679,           485,         1,C,    201001,    222.76,      201311
  14112013,14-NOV-13
    701679,           485,         1,C,    201002,    222.76,      201311
  14112013,14-NOV-13
    701679,           485,         1,C,    201003,    222.76,      201311
  14112013,14-NOV-13
    701679,           485,         1,C,    201004,    229.69,      201311
  14112013,14-NOV-13
```